# How to remove line number when you paste to sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I copy some lines of code and paste to sqlplus, it have line number for each line so the query would be invalid (see attached image).
Could anyone help me solve that: How to config so that after pasting the copied code, it has no line number in sqlplus?

[image]

Comment: This is just an artifact of the display when you paste in multiple lines at once, and can be ignored. It should not affect the execution of your query or SQL commands. Are you getting a specific error back?

Answer (score 1):

try for your current sqlplus session before copypaste

```
set sqlprompt ''
set sqlnumber off
```

[SQL*Plus® User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm)

*SET SQLN[UMBER] {ON | OFF}

Sets the prompt for the second and subsequent lines of a SQL command or PL/SQL block.

*SET SQLP[ROMPT] {SQL> | text}

Sets the SQL*Plus command prompt.

example:

```
SQL> select *
from
dual
;  2    3    4

D
-
X

SQL> set sqlnumber off
SQL> set sqlprompt ''
select *
from
dual
;

D
-
X
```

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation